# does not work event to element on textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function addRow(event) {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.name = "bar";
    element1.id = 'bar2';
    element1.onchange = "getdata(this.id,this.value)"
    element1.onkeydown = "getcost(event,this.id,this.value)";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
}
```

this code is in javascript.i want to add onchange and onkeydown event to input textbox.this code run on onclick button.

Comment: yoo can use addEventListener to add event for element.

Answer (score 0):

you can try for following

get reference from "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp"

object.onchange = function(){yourscript};
in your case it will become...

element1.onchange = function()

```
                {
                   getdata(this.id,this.value); 

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

use addEventListener.

```
element1.addEventListener ("change",function(){ getdata(this.id,this.value)} );
element1.addEventListener ("keydown",function() { getcost(event,this.id,this.value) });
```

Answer (score 0):

First created an element on document ready.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
       var element = document.createElement('input');
       element.type='text';
       element.name='bar'
       element.id='bar2';
       element.onchange = function(){ getdata(this); }
       element.onkeydown = function(){ getcost(event,this); }
       document.body.appendChild(element);
  }
}
```

Function which are attached to the events.

```
function getcost(e, obj){
    //Do your stuff here
    alert(obj.id);
    alert(obj.value);

}


 function getdata(obj){
    //Do your stuff here
    alert(obj.id);
    alert(obj.value);
 }
```